# Codeigniter database session update inconsistency

Tags: database, codeigniter, session

In Codeigniter, the function `session->userdata($item)` is used to retrieve session data and the definition of this function in `Session` class is :

```
function userdata($item)
{
    return ( ! isset($this->userdata[$item])) ? FALSE : $this->userdata[$item];
}
```

**Now the problem is this:**

Each time a script is executed, a session object is created and the retrieved data is persistent untill end of the script. So if another script for example update session values, new values will be stored in DB, but retrieved data in other session objects are not updated and it makes an obvious inconsistency and inaccuracy in data.
I think it can be a serious problem in many cases.

Is it right or I'm misunderstanding something here? And if

Answer (score -1):

IN codeigniter session object is created during the class initialization and userdata(session values) are updated every time user makes request. You can view whole session object via below piece of code:

```
print_r($this->session);
```

This will show you the complete session object with all necessary configurations you have set in your config file for session related variables like:

```
sess_encrypt_cookie, sess_use_database,sess_expiration ..etc
```

plus your current session user data. Now when you make next request session values are overridden by the new one or old values are just replaced by the new one. So there is no chance of data duplicacy or inconsistancy. It is recommended to use session table whenever you are saving large amount of data in session.

Comment: I've added the function `userdata()` definition in my question. according to this, how are session values updated *every time user makes request* ??

Comment: As you have mentioned that "another script for example update session values, new values will be stored in DB", session values are updated on user request for respective session variable only for which some update has been done i.e. for eg. If there is autologout function where timestamp stored in session after the successful login, and is updated on each user request where some autologout function is called that checks the current difference of session timestamp and the current one, if it exceeds as per defined limit then user logouts otherwise update session timestamp with the current one.

Comment: session userdata doesn't get updated automatically but via manual script subject to requirement otherwise will be persistant throughout the active session